# SQL query to get max id

Tags: sql

I have a table named `test` in which two fields and there data is listed as below

```
id    test_no
---   -------
1     2
2     2
3     2
4     2 
5     3
6     3
```

now I want to get maximum `test_no` in my case I wan to get now 3 and 3 (because there are two counts of 3)
so I use this query but it gives me 3 and 2
I want this

```
id    test_no
---   -------
5     3
6     3
```

my query is

```
SELECT MAX( `test_no` )
FROM `test`
GROUP BY `test_no`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
select `id`,`test_no`
from `tab`
where `test_no` = (
                  SELECT MAX( `test_no` )
                  FROM `test`
                )
```

Comment: I use this but it gives me this error `Subquery returns more than 1 row`

Answer (score 0):

You could try this query:

```
select * from test 
where test_no = (select max(test_no) from test)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way :

```
SELECT * FROM test
WHERE TEST_NO = (SELECT MAX(TEST_NO) FROM test)
```

Thanks
Manoj